# Removing the opacity and time interval when a layer is removed or hidden in Core Animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

It seems when I remove the animation from a `CALayer` or set it to hidden the layer fades out over about half of a second before it is removed, whereas I would like the it to stop when i want it too.

It should stop as soon as the `CALayer` has been tapped, but what seems likes a fade out effect is applied to the layer. The animation moves the `CALayer` vertically and when it is removed on tap you can just about see it fading out.

The reason I need it to be removed as soon as it is tapped is because a UIImageView replaces it in it's position and runs a keyframe images animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can control this automatic animation by [disabling layer actions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Transactions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006096-SW6):

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
                 forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
[aLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, my animation is a `CAKeyFrameAnimation` which follows a path - but I don't think that should be a problem right?

Comment: I'm not sure why disabling the actions as you do in your other answer would be any different than disabling them in the way I described. Odd!

Comment: That's what I thought too, I also looked at the code you sent me and the link incase it was a typo or something, but it was all ok and other people seem to use the same code for the same problem, it must be a problem on my end somewhere

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now, I figured the best way is to effectively nullify the `action` property of the parent layer.

```
parentLayer.actions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNull null], @"onOrderIn",
                            [NSNull null], @"onOrderOut",
                            [NSNull null], @"sublayers",
                            [NSNull null], @"contents",
                            [NSNull null], @"bounds",
                            nil];

[childLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
```

In my case I only needed to the 'sublayers' data in the `NSDict`:

```
parentLayer.actions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNull null], @"sublayers",
                            nil];

[childLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
```